# Android In-app billing error: Illegal state for operation (launchPurchaseFlow): IAB helper is not set up

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I tried setting up InApp purchases for a donation with the [guide provided by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) but when I call the activity (which should return if it was a success or not) but it throws this error:

```
In-app billing error: Illegal state for operation (launchPurchaseFlow): IAB helper is not set up
```

The activity is called with this method:

```
public boolean donation() {
        int success = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Donate.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, success);
        if (success != 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

And the Donate class (which I tried coding with the guide) looks like this:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import maturaarbeit.nicola_pfister.marks.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Donate extends Activity {

    IabHelper mHelper;

    private static final String TAG = "Donate";
    private String payload;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String base64EncodedPublicKey = getKey();
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result); 
                }
            }
        });

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);    //Add shared preferences
        payload = prefs.getString("devpayload", null);
        if (payload == null) {
            payload = getPayload();

            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("devpayload", payload)
            .apply();
        }
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "donation_1chf", 1, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
        finish();
    }

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " +result);
                return;
            }
            else if (info.getDeveloperPayload().equals(payload)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }

    private String getKey() {
        //Code for building public key
    }

    private String getPayload() {
      SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
      {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

}

It is supposed to generate a dev payload which is stored in shared prefs if there isn't already one. If you need any additional information feel free to ask.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait for `onIabSetupFinishedListener` to return before calling `launchPurchaseFlow` - move those lines into your `onIabSetupFinishedListener`'s `onIabSetupFinished` method to ensure that the `IabHelper`'s setup is complete:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result); 
            }
            else { // Only launch the purchase flow if setup succeeded
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Donate.this, "donation_1chf", 1,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I try to put the launchPurchaseFlow into onIabSetupFinished I get this error:
The method launchPurchaseFlow(Activity, String, int, IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener) in the type IabHelper is not applicable for the arguments (new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener(){}, String, int, IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener)

Comment: @BlueHazard - sounds like you need to replace `this` with `Donate.this` to reference the activity. I've added code that demonstrates this.

Comment: You were right. I did it exactly like you did but I hadn't changed the context. Next time I see a "this" context I'll try this first.

Comment: @BlueHazard - just remember that `this` refers to the class you are running in (in your case, the listener itself). You have to refer to outer classes by name using the `OuterClass.this` syntax.

Comment: It works now but I can't get it to return correctly. Do you know how to let it return a boolean?

Comment: @BlueHazard - you have the source of `IabHelper` so you can certainly modify that to do whatever you want. I would suggest asking another question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 5):

You should use **real device** for app billing because when using emulator some parameters are being null and it causes runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you have targetSdkVersion 30+ you have to query the market in your AndroidManifest and declare that your app wants to use its services.
use this to see if you already have that among the list

```
for (ApplicationInfo a : getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)){
    System.out.println(a.name);
}
```

if not, you have to declare the market's package in your AndroidManifest
these two are for bazaar and myket, don't know about playstore, Huwai or Galaxy

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.farsitel.bazaar" />
    <package android:name="ir.mservices.market" />
</queries>
```

if you don't know their packages, you can add the intent those stores use, that way you also declare that you query every other app that uses that specific intent. which every store have to use.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

when you use this query, you can call the method getInstalledApplications I mentioned earlier and get the new list, find the store's package and just replace your query with the package only